# How does kubernetes get the imagefs.available and nodefs.available eviction signals?

Tags: kubernetes

Two signals(`imagefs.available` and `nodefs.available`) in [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#eviction-signals) caught my attention. How does kubernetes or kubelet get these signals value? How can I manually look up these values in my nodes?

My cluster specification:

- `kubernetes v1.21.6` (vanilla)
- `containerd v1.5.7`
- 1 master node, 3 worker node

Answer (score -2):

As stated in the documentation, `nodefs.available` and `imagefs.available` are *Eviction Signals, kubelet uses eviction signals to make eviction decisions by comparing the signals to eviction thresholds, which are the minimum amount of the resource that should be available on the node*. They are set by default by Kubernetes.

> The kubelet has the following default hard eviction thresholds:
> memory.available<100Mi nodefs.available<10% imagefs.available<15% nodefs.inodesFree<5%

There is no way to check the eviction policy info unless hard eviction thresholds are defined and set in [kubelet config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/).

You can only check the default thresholds by looking at `kubelet` flags.

```
kubelet --help | grep eviction
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bryan. I don't understand the stark difference between `nodefs` and `imagefs`.

How do I know if I have `imagefs`?

Comment: @nulluisinverba nodefs: the node's main filesystem, used for local disk volumes, emptyDir, log storage, and more. For example, nodefs contains /var/lib/kubelet/. For imagefs: An optional filesystem that container runtimes use to store container images and container writable layers. These 2 file system are used by Kubelet by default. You can use the command I've shared with you to check the default eviction threshold.

Comment: Thank you for your help Bryan. I think you said `imagefs` is optional. 

How do I know if this optional thing is active or inactive? Is `imagefs` active or not in my cluster? I am looking for the answer to this question.

Comment: @nulluisinverba as mentioned before this are set by default by Kubernetes, and regarding their status you can only check their threshold or custom set it. To clarify, I didn't say it is optional, it is all based on Kubernetes documentation, it only means that imagefs will be used by container runtime to store container images, filesystem will be active once you execute a container runtime. For added infrormation you can check this link. https://v1-20.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#eviction-thresholds